# MVC3 Regular Expressions Designer.cs

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, model

Taking the database first approach in MVC3 all of my models are created and stored in a designer.cs

In the code below, I want to force a regex validation of the NDC property. The input needs to resemble 1234-1234-12 or 4 digits a dash 4 digits a dash 2 digits.

```
public partial class Drug : EntityObject

{
    #region Factory Method

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.String NDC
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Rx NDC")]
        [RegularExpression(@"\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a correctly formatted NDC")]

        get
        {
            return _NDC;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_NDC != value)
            {
                OnNDCChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("NDC");
                _NDC = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
                ReportPropertyChanged("NDC");
                OnNDCChanged();
            }
        }
    }I dont know how to apply the code above in the code below because I get the this error:
```

Error   13  Attribute 'Required' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field, param' declarations. C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\320Final -Updated\320Final\Models\DBModel.Designer.cs

Comment: What's a "get/set method" in C#?  Are you confusing it with Java?  To which member in the supplied class are you trying to add these attributes?

Comment: @David  I am trying to add the attributes to the NDC attribute.  When I say get/set method I am referring to how the get and set above is coded rather than something like                       public string NDC { get; set; }

Comment: It's still just a property, not a method.  There's no overlap between the two.  Can you show a full class with the attributes applied which generates the error?  Preferably taking out as much of the other generated code as possible, reducing to the minimum code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @David I have edited the code above to reflect your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set the attributes *inside* of the property:

```
public global::System.String NDC
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Rx NDC")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a correctly formatted NDC")]
    get
    {
        return _NDC;
    }
...
```

You need to set them on the property itself:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Rx NDC")]
[RegularExpression(@"\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d-\d\d", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a correctly formatted NDC")]
public global::System.String NDC
{
    get
    {
        return _NDC;
    }
....
```